# invalid data, chunk must be string of buffer, not object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a bit of an issue with some code that was left from the last developer.  I'm trying to get csscomb to run on sublime and update it to the point where it works with the newer packages.  I've run into this error when trying to run the package on a scss file. The full error is pasted below

```
CSScomb error:
net.js:658
throw new TypeError(
^

TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
at Socket.write (net.js:658:11)
at combCSS (/Users/michaelr/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/sublime-csscomb/csscomb.js:39:20)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/michaelr/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/sublime-csscomb/csscomb.js:18:5)
```

And the full code is below. I haven't seen anybody run into an issue with this plugin like this so I'm a bit out of my league as far as debugging node unfortunately.  I've googled and fixed a lot of the errors I've encountered but I couldn't find this one.  Any help would be super appreciated!

```
// Set up Variables
var CSScomb = require ('./node_modules/csscomb/lib/csscomb');
var comb = new CSScomb();

// Set encoding
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

// Capture data
var input = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
input += data;
});

// All data is read, run comb:
process.stdin.on('end', function() {
combCSS();
});

// Parse css
function combCSS() {
// Apply configuration:
comb.configure(getConfig());

// Parse css:
try {
    var combedCSS = comb.processString(input, {'syntax': 'scss'});
} catch (error) {
    // On error, output original css:
    process.stdout.write(input);
    // Show error message:
    process.stderr.write(error.message);
    console.log(error.message);
    process.exit(1);
}

// On success, output parsed css:
process.stdout.write(combedCSS);
process.exit(); 
}

function getConfig() {
var config = {};

// Use current project's root folder as a starting point.
// If no project is active, use current folder as a fallback:
var configpath = process.env.EDITOR_PROJECT_PATH ||   process.env.EDITOR_DIRECTORY_PATH;

// Search for custom config file recursively up to the home folder:
configpath = CSScomb.getCustomConfigPath(configpath + '/.csscomb.json');

try {
    // Try to load config file:
    config = require(configpath);
} catch (error) {
    // If no config file is available, use default config:
    config = getDefaultConfig();
}

return config;
}

function getDefaultConfig() {
var config = {};

var configZen = CSScomb.getConfig('zen');

// Copy only sort-order data:
config['sort-order'] = configZen['sort-order'];

// If sort-order is separated into sections, add an empty section at top:
if (config['sort-order'].length > 1) {
    config['sort-order'].unshift([]);
}

// Add sort-order info for SCSS, Sass and Less functions into the first section:
config['sort-order'][0].unshift('$variable', '$include', '$import');

// Add configuration that mimics most of the settings from Espresso:
config['block-indent']                    = "  ";
config['rules-delimiter']                 = 1
config['strip-spaces']                    = true;
config['always-semicolon']                = true;
config['vendor-prefix-align']             = true;
config['unitless-zero']                   = true;
config['leading-zero']                    = false;
config['quotes']                          = 'single';
config['color-case']                      = 'lower';
config['eof-newline']                     = true;
config['remove-empty-rulesets']           = true;
config['element-case']                    = 'lower';
config['color-shorthand']                 = false;
config['space-before-colon']              = '';
config['space-after-colon']               = ' ';
config['space-before-combinator']         = ' ';
config['space-after-combinator']          = ' ';
config['space-before-opening-brace']      = ' ';
config['space-after-opening-brace']       = '\n';
config['space-before-closing-brace']      = '\n';
config['space-before-selector-delimiter'] = '';
config['space-after-selector-delimiter']  = '\n';
config['space-between-declarations']      = '\n';

return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there, have you tried deleting csscomb and installing the latest version?

Also you have a syntax error at this line `config['rules-delimiter'] = 1`